# Can I get back an item I lost?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I placed Auriel's Bow in a chest at Nightcaller Temple. When I came back it was gone, what do I do? I'm playing on XBox, not PC.

Comment: If it was recent enough, I'd just load the save before you deposited the bow, and then continue from there.

Comment: yep since you are on the xbox reloading a save is your only option

Answer (score 3):

Because of how Skyrim is programmed with the [Radiant Quest System](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Radiant_Quests) (which resets dungeons and creates random quests) placing items in chests you find is a bad idea as an area will reset causing any stored items to be lost. the only safe places to store items is in user brought homes such as Breezehome in Whiterun.

As for getting it back chances are no, if it's a Quest Reward then it's gone, if it wasn't you could try and reforge/buy an incidental item

Comment: Auriel's is a quest reward.

Comment: @zpletan ok, i didn't know as having never gotten it

Comment: fyi auriel's bow is unique and has an unique effect, you can't replace it through reforging or enchanting.